# webpack-dev-server returns 504 while backend returns 204

Tags: node.js, windows, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server

Here is an error text (app crashes at all 204 reponses):

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /rest/profiles/change-password from site.loc:3005 to https://site.loc (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Debugged backend response. It returns 204 status code with empty body (data = null). If I build an app everything is working fine. One more moment: it doesn't occur at other developer's MAC OS.

My webpack devServer config:

```
  devServer: {
    contentBase: PATHS.dist,
    host: appDomain,
    proxy: {
      '/rest': {
        target: appUrl,
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
      },
    ...
 }
```

My enviroment:

```
Windows 10 Pro x64
node version: v12.18.4
webpack-dev-server: "^3.11.0",
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

I spent about 3 days on that error, myabe this answer could help anyone...
I didn't figure out why this error occur, good people helped me with this code:

```
    proxy: {
      '/rest': {
        target: appUrl,
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
          console.log(proxyRes.statusCode);
        },
        onError: function (err, req, res) {
          console.log(`req.body: ${req.body}`); // here it returned undefined
          console.log(`err.code: ${err.code}`);
          if (err.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
            res.writeHead(204, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.end();
          }
        },
      },
```

Previously tried to do this using webpack-dev-server bypass method, axios interceptors, but with no success.